# Can't burn Manjaro on USB with Startup Disk Creator

Tags: ubuntu, usb, manjaro, burning

I tried to use Startup Disk Creator on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine to burn Manjaro 20.0.3 xfce to a bootable usb stick. I always use this tool without any problem, e.g. Xubuntu, Debian. But I can't find Manjaro iso file to proceed:

[image]

Here is my Startup Disk Creator version:

```
$ usb-creator-gtk --version
0.3.3
```

Why do I encounter this the problem with Manjaro?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: I wrote on the title. I can't burn it. I can't select manjaro on the iso panel of the program.

Comment: You can't burn a USB stick, only a CD or DVD - unless we're talking literal fire of course

Comment: @Panki The term might be disputable but it is clear.

Comment: You can use 1. Disks alias `gnome-disks` that is bundled with Ubuntu, or 2. if you want to install [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). It can clone a live drive of Manjaro (but not make a persistent live drive of that distro). -- The Startup Disk Creator 'does not want to' create drives that lack some internal structure typical for Ubuntu (and similar distros).

Answer (score 3):

I used Gnome Multiboot. It had no problem burning Manjaro ISOs from within Xubuntu and it's even in the Ubuntu repositories already.

```
sudo apt install gnome-multi-writer
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu package is not capable of making bootable USB for many non Ubuntu distributions

For Manjaro try using [Ventoy](https://ventoy.net/en/index.html) ; [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) or [Multiboot USB](https://mbusb.aguslr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use dd command wish is too sample

```
sudo dd status=progress if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdX
```

change the path to the iso and the device